# htaccess rewrite order id remove ?order_id but use slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Been stuck with this question for hours. I've tried tons of things throughout the internet, but can't get it solved.

So, what I currently have is: `https://example.com/order/index.php?order_id=12345`

What I've been wanting to achieve is `https://example.com/order/12345`

My `.htaccess` file looks like this, and is located in the `/order/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ .index.php?order_id=$1
```

I got this from another post on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to get it working.

I feel like I might be doing something wrong. I hope anyone is able to assist me here, have a great day guys!

Comment: "I got this from another post on StackOverflow" - really? Care to provide the link... there's a couple of obvious errors in both the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ and _substitution_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /order/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# n is no of length
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{n})$ index.php?order_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Although if the order id is always a number as suggested in the question then a more specific `(\d+)` would probably be more appropriate, or even use a range specifier if the order is always a known length.

Comment: check this tested working, order_id is always no with specified range

Answer (score -1):

This is what exactly you need i guess.

```
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule order(/)(.+)$ /index.php?order_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: However... "is located in the `/order/` directory" and `index.php` is also located in the `/order/` subdirectory.